# PHP - Weird behaviour after calling functions in a map

Tags: php, firefox, localhost, anonymous

I'm experiencing quite a strange reaction from the browser when invoking this PHP script.

```
<?php
    $map = array(
        'a' => function(){
                print_r('a');
            },

        'b' => function(){
                print_r('b');
            }
    );  
    $map($_GET['v']);
?>
```

I already noticed that there is a mistake there. The syntax of the call is wrong, as it should be like this:

```
$map[$_GET['v']]();
```

The thing is that the reaction of the browser to this mistake is not what it should be.

The result of running this script is a 'The connection was reset' message. The server is up and running correctly, as other PHP files (and this one after correcting the mistake) run perfectly.

But what is actually puzzling me is what the navigation bar of the browser does. When I punch in the URL

```
localhost/cerdo.php?v=a
```

the content of the bar changes to

```
www.localhost.com/cerdo.php?v=a
```

The www.localhost.com part seems to happen only in Firefox. I've tried it on Chromium and, despite showing a similar message ('No data received') the URL stays the same.

What is happening? Does this make any sense? Shouldn't PHP be reporting a syntax error? And why on earth would Firefox redirect to www.localhost.com?

Comment: your code is just fine.. see this [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uxv-0gf) but check if you are doing something else in your code!! please show other code blocks might be responsible of the error occurring

Comment: The script consists only of the code shown, so there are no other possible culprits.

Comment: your redirect or something like that

Comment: NB: The above code is only correct under PHP 5.3+; if you're using an earlier version you can't use anonymous functions.

Comment: Surprisingly using PHP 5.3.1 I got "Fatal error: Function name must be a string in prueba.php on line 12".

Comment: Ok, so if I were trying to debug this, I'd open up firebug's network tab, tick the "preserve" option so you can still see responses after the redirect and then trigger the problem. By examining the response, you'll either see a redirect of some sort or something odd which is causing FF to interpret it as a redirect. I'd be really interested to know what the full response looks like (including headers)

Answer (score 1):

**Shouldn't PHP be reporting a syntax error?**

No. If PHP is not reporting `$map($_GET['v']);` as syntax error is because it is expecting the code to be syntactically valid. So it ends up executing some very weird stuff that you are not expecting. This results in redirecting your browser to some unexplainable location.

The key here is to understand what `$map($_GET['v']);` actually means.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection doesn't have anything to do with your code. How is your environment setup, e.g. are you using Xampp etc.? In that case make sure there is any index.php or .htaccess or anything else that contains a redirection script in your web root.

Comment: The thing is that that redirection only takes place with that code. If I just correct the syntax mistake, the file is loaded correctly.